# How does the computer distinguish a number and a character?

Tags: memory, operating-system

Based on the ASCII table, when we store 'TAB' and decimal 9 to the memory, they are both stored as "1001".  How does the computer know it's a 'TAB' or a decimal 9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The computer doesn't "know" what type a specific address in memory is, that knowledge is baked into the instructions of your program.

When you write a program and it sees your variable, the compiler creates assembly code that writes that piece of data somewhere, and there is some other code somewhere else that reads a memory address and *interprets it as a char*. The knowledge that it *is* a char is not stored in memory.  The location of that memory address is the only thing that ties these two operations together.

When that location is read, the assembly doesn't say "see what data type is there", it just says "load this location of memory and treat it as a char". If, for example, something has overwritten that memory address with something other than a char, the CPU will just load that that memory as a char anyway, and all kinds of weird stuff can happen as a result.

For example, in the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x; 
    x = 9;
    char* y;
    y = &x;
    printf("\"%s\" \"%d\"\n", y, x);
    printf("%p\n%p", y, &x);
    return 0;
}
```

You will get output like:

```
"       " "9"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
0x7ffd401ce68c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
0x7ffd401ce68c
```

So we see that the *same* location in memory is being treated as a char, and as an int.  The value in memory doesn't know or care what it is being used as.

Comment: Do you mean there are places reserved for characters?  Anything stored in that place will be treated as a char.  Other variable types will be similar.  Thanks~

Comment: no, i mean that the memory doesn't know or care what type is being stored in each location, your program is the only place that will "know" that the memory in some location should be treated a certain way.

Comment: So in this case, the CPU read and returned what data it found at the given address until a null was found, and the C compiler interpreted it as an 8-bit char, resulting in ASCII character 9 (horizontal tab). Is that correct? However a typical C integer takes 32 bits in memory (represented as 0x01000009 on a little-endian system?). If the CPU indeed reads this information until the null and C interprets it as a char, why isn't the output four chars? I'm clearly wrong, but where?

Comment: I think I figured out where I'm wrong. The representation of integer 9 in memory in C is 0x09000000. I changed your code to include `printf("\"%c%c%c%c\" \"%d\"\n", *y, *(y+1), *(y+2), *(y+3), x);` to find out. I'm not sure why the representation is thus, but that can wait :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me use the venerable VAX as an example. Suppose you have defined 8 bytes of memory at some location:

```
location:
     .ASCII /ABCDEFGH/
```

The instruction

```
 MOVC3   location, 8, some_other_location
```

treats the memory as characters.

The instruction

```
ADDL2 location, R0
```

treats that same memory as an integer value

The instruction

```
MULD2 location, R8
```

treats that same memory as a floating point value.

The instruction:

```
jmp location
```

treats the same memory as code (but will probably puke).

Memory is memory. How it is interpreted depends up on the instruction operating on the memory. The computer has no idea what is stored in a location. That is up to the programmer to decide.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between text data or any other types of *data* per se, so the computer can't distinguish between an ASCII character or a plain number in memory.

However, the *process* acting on that data treats the different memory contents differently and comes with the "knowledge" of the type of data baked into its instruction sequence. A call to [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)() for example requires the argument to be a [string of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling) (null-terminated character string). So there you have it, the knowledge is in the process, not the data.

This can lead to problems, because it is up to the human programmer to make sure that the right types of arguments (data) are passed over to a specific function (process). - Luckily, compilers (and other helpers used during development at [compile time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time), or before e.g. by using [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis)) also "know" how things have to be typed (in the case of [strongly typed languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)), so that a faulty program will usually not compile. - But in any case, for example in C, you can treat any memory contents as whatever type of data you would like to (e.g. by [type casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#C-like_languages)), with some restrictions even as executable code.

At run time, there's (almost) nothing preventing a program from interpreting data at an arbitrary memory location as ASCII text or plain numbers, it's just a matter of representation.

However, there exist conventions on how a program is structured, and where it stores text, as static strings known at compile time i.e. plain text. Usually, they are placed in the [.data or .rodata segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Data) of a program (usually not in the .text segment). You can scan a binary program by using [strings](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) like this:

```
$ strings /usr/bin/strings
```

Or if you want to know more about the .data / .rodata segments, binutils' [objdump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) might come in handy:

```
$ objdump -h /usr/bin/strings
$ objdump --full-contents --section .rodata /usr/bin/strings
```

The same can be done with a hex editor:

```
$ xxd <my-binary>
$ xxd /usr/bin/strings
```

At the end it is up to the individual program to *know* how to treat its memory, and how to interpret the individual bits of binary data in it. The program is usually running inside a an operating system, that defines other types of restrictions on what regions of memory are accessible and how, and the program might be talking to other processes outside or inside the box (access permissions, system APIs that demand a certain type of data, e.g. text or binary data). But again, in this case the knowledge also lies in the processes, not in the data itself. The hardware (i.e. the processor and the memory (RAM, FLASH...)) doesn't treat text data fundamentally differently from other types of data.